# How to pass an Object of a Class that implements an Interface with just knowing the Class of the Interface to a Method and add it to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

Lets say that I have an Interface and multiple Classes that implement this Interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
   public String getString();
   public String getAnotherString();
}
```

Now I have classes that implement this Interface:

```
public class MyClass1 implements myInterface {
   @Override
   public String getString() {
       return "A String";
   }
   @Override
   public String getAnotherString() {
      return "foo";
   }
}
```

And:

```
public class MyClass2 implements myInterface {
    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return "Another String";
    }
    @Override
    public String getAnotherString() {
       return "bar";
    }
}
```

How can I let a Method accept Objects of Classes which implement `myInterface` then?

```
public <T extends MyInterface> void aMethod(T object) {
    objects.add(object); //⚡ doesn't work
}
```

This works but it won't let me add those objects to an ArrayList that I declared like that then:

```
ArrayList<? extends MyInterface> objects = new ArrayList<>();
```

What am I doing wrong? :/

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why can't you just use `ArrayList<myInterface> objects`

Comment: Why not `public void aMethod(myInterface obj)` and `ArrayList<myInterface>` ?

Comment: You do know that oyu have two classes called `myClass1`? Also, please respect Java naming conventions: Classes and interfaces are supposed to be written in `UpperCamelCase`.

Comment: Oh god.. I could have sworn that this was the first thing I tried. Now I literally spent 2 hours of research without noticing this. But thank you for pointing this out. :)

Comment: Short answer is to never use `? extends` or `super`.  They are needed in some complex cases, but, IMO, most of those cases can and should be redesigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per generics for **? extends MyInterface** only getters are allowed

```
ArrayList<? extends MyInterface> objects = new ArrayList<>();
you can only do get of type MyInterface and Object
MyInterface myInterace = objects.get(0);
Object myInterace = objects.get(0);
```

For your case to work you can use `ArrayList<MyInterface> objects = new ArrayList<>();`

Now suppose if addition to MyInterface had been allowed then what wrong could happen via a simple example

```
Long longValue = 20L; 
List<Long> longList = new ArrayList();
longList.add(longValue);

Integer i =10;
List<? extends Number> sNumber = longList ;// longList can be assigned to ? extends Number
sNumber.add(i); // if this was allowed
longValue = longList.get(1);   // we will get an exception (class cast exception)
```

Hence compiler doesn't allow that setter